# Android: Upload string as text file to skydrive

Tags: android, http, onedrive

I would like to upload a string as a text file to skydrive from my android application. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you try something ??? if any then post your code..

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you have to create a file from the user Entered String, and then save this .txt file on your Server(skydrive)
Its the code which will create a file from the string.

```
 private String filename = "MySampleFile.txt";
 private String filepath = "MyFileStorage";
 File myInternalFile;

      ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
      File directory = contextWrapper.getDir(filepath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      myInternalFile = new File(directory , filename);

      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myInternalFile);
        fos.write(myInputText.getText().toString().getBytes());
        fos.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }finally{
       Toast.makeText(context, MySampleFile.txt saved to Internal Storage...", 1000).show;
       }
```

Now save this file in skydrive using skydrive api.